# Any chance of formatting Date object returned by resultset getDate() method

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I want to skip the parsing of date and formatting it. Instead i directly want to fetch the date from database in custom format. Is this possible ?

Comment: you are asking about the functionalities of the database, so you should include your database and its version in the question. This question is not at all related to java-ee, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change your SQL query to format the date. For example, if you use oracle, you need to use the function TO_CHAR(dateColumn, 'YYYY/MM/DD'), and that will return a String column with the date formatted as '2012/09/14'.

Answer (score 0):

You can set format in your query. (My example is run on sqlserver)

something like..

```
SELECT CONVERT (VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 103)
```

for more detail http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices2005/centurydateformat/

Answer (score 0):

You need look into the functions provided by the database vendor.

For example, in Oracle we can use the following syntax in the SQL itself

TO_CHAR('date', 'format')

So go thru the documentation  database you use.