# resultSet.getDate converting year of date incorretly

Tags: java, spring, resultset, jdbctemplate

I am using spring JdbcTemplate with Oracle database. Following is the data into database:

```
12-04-15(dd-mm-yy)
15-10-22(dd-mm-yy)
```

when I am reading date as ResultSet.getDate(Column_Name) it is converting date as follows(I am not applying any format while reading date):

```
2015-04-12
0022-10-15 (here 22 is converted to 0022 that is incorrect it should be 2022)
```

Below is the versions of frameworks:

```
Oracle Version:11.2.0.4
java version:1.7
Spring Vaersion: 4.1.1.RELEASE
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any chance of formatting Date object returned by resultset getDate() method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422370/any-chance-of-formatting-date-object-returned-by-resultset-getdate-method)

Comment: That I have seen already. Same output is coming. and also I want to know why it is converting 15 to 2015 but 22 to 0022.